# How to populate a Combobox with items and one textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two `ComboBoxes`, based on the selection of the first, the seconds gets populated.

How to make the second `ComboBox` act or display a `TextBox` when **Other** is selected in first one, so user can enter numbers/letters.

## C#

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {        
     public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; private set; }

     private ObservableCollection<string> _Veh = new ObservableCollection<string>();

     private ObservableCollection<string> _VehTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>();
     private ObservableCollection<string> _cars = new ObservableCollection<string>();
     private ObservableCollection<string> _planes = new ObservableCollection<string>();

     public ObservableCollection<string> Veh
     {
         get { return _Veh; }
         set { SetProperty(ref _Veh, value); }
     }        

     public ObservableCollection<string> VehTypes
     {
         get { return _VehTypes; }
         set { SetProperty(ref _VehTypes, value); }
     }        

     public MyViewModel()
     {        
         UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnUpdate);

         _Veh.Add("Cars");
         _Veh.Add("Planes");
         _Veh.Add("Other");

         _Cars.Add("GM");
         _Cars.Add("BMW");
         _Cars.Add("Toyota");
         _Cars.Add("Honda");

         _planes.Add("AirBus");
         _planes.Add("Boing");        
    }

    private void OnUpdate(object myobj)
    {
        _VehTypes.Clear();
        // Add new vehTypes based on _cars and _planes
    }
}
```

## wpf

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboVeh" ItemsSource="{Binding Veh}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboVeh}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="ComboVehTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding VehTypes}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `ContentControl` with a trigger that sets the `ContentTemplate` property to a `DataTemplate` that contains a `TextBox` when "Other" is selected:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboVeh" ItemsSource="{Binding Veh}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboVeh}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboVeh}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="ComboVehTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.VehTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Content" Value="Other">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Amazing solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your goal can be achieved by following:

- Add a new 'TextBox' (this will handle the text when "Other" is selected in first dropdown) in your view.
- Bind the **Visibility** property of both - second dropdown and this new TextBox from ViewModel and make them visible accordingly.

Like, if 'Other' is selected in first dropdown set 'Visibility' of second dropdown to 'Collapsed' and 'Visibility' of TextBox to 'Visible' else vice-versa.

So, at once only one element will be visible to user - either second dropdown or a TextBox based on the selection in first dropdown.

You are already handling second dropdown selection so all you need is to bind the 'Text' property of new TextBox from ViewModel so if 'Other' is selected in first dropdown you can use that Text (entered by user in TextBox) for further manipulation or to store in DB.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. However, I'm looking for one control that can achieve it.